# Have any one Worked on The fillable pdf in sales force

Tags: salesforce, pdf-generation, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer, fillable

hi I am working on the  fillable pdf in Salesforce, i have uploaded the pdf in the static resource in Salesforce , now need to handle the data to fill in it and download the file , can any suggestions to achieve it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no functionality in Apex to interact with fillable PDFs. While it's possible to interact with binary formats such as PDF in Apex, it's difficult, slow, and subject to the extensive limitations of the Salesforce governor limits. You'd have to implement this from scratch based on your knowledge of the PDF format.

You will likely have much more success either building PDF manipulation functionality in JavaScript on the front end, or calling out to an external service on Heroku or elsewhere that uses PDF libraries available in some other stack to do this work.

Answer (score 0):

- Salesforce does not support inputs on generated pdf via Visualforce
  pages.
- To achieve this functionality, you can **create a form with all the
  inputs that are required** in the pdf.
- Once the user fills in the information in the created form and submits it, **generate the pdf with the filled information by the user**.

**Bonus:** you can save the filled-in information as well by creating a record under the object for future reference (data is everything)